# How to italicize plot titles in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to graph up some data regarding counts of species. I've produced the accompanying graph but I was wondering how I would go about changing the species names to italics?  My graph:

[image]

Here is the current code that I'm using:

```
ggplot(data=counts.df, aes(x=species, y=counts)) + 
   geom_boxplot() +
   labs(x = "Species") +
   labs(y = "Mean Frequency") +
   coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 2):

With `ggplot2` we can modify the axis title along the y axis with `theme`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

[image]

If you want the titles of both axis italicized, we can do the following:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

[image]